# Filter search data from Microsoft Access Database and filter in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

I use this code to try and make the application filter the text in the textbox but it refuses to do so and an error message keeps popping up. Here is the code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace TestBarcode
{
    public partial class StaffHome : Form
    {
        private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        public StaffHome()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Projects\POS\Database\MainDatabase_POS.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
        }

        private void StaffHome_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                string query = "select * from InventoryManagement";
                command.CommandText = query;

                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
            }
       }
       try
       {
            connection = new OleDbConnection();
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * from InventoryManagement where ID like '" + textBox1.Text + "%'", connection);

            OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
```

Is there a way to make this happen? If so,  please help. Thanks.

EDIT: Here is an image of the error msg.
[Error msg Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTi59.png)

Comment: First: the code above doesn't seems to be compilable. (Are these two different methods? If so please add the relevant code) Second. What is the type of the column ID on the datatable InventoryManagement? Third, what is exactly the error message? I am sorry but if you don't add these important information your question belong to the category "Unclear what you are asking"

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.
First, it is the same code and I assume it is because the program works fine until I insert a text in the textbox.
Second, there are a few other columns including:
ID, BarcodeID, Price, Quantity.
Third, I have edit the above text and add in an image of my error. 
Again. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second command calls NEW on the OleDbConnection variable. The result is that this recreates the OleDbConnection but misses the initialization of the required connectionstring

In this context you should still use the global object and do not create a new connection.
So just remove this line

```
 // This creates a new OleDbConnection without the connection string
 connection = new OleDbConnection();
```

However I dislike a lot using a global object for a connection. The connection internally uses unmanaged resources that can be difficult to handle correctly in case of exceptions and it is always preferable to create a local connection and keep global only the connection string. This pattern allows the introduction of the using statement that destroys correctly the connection and frees the unmanaged resources kept by the connection

Comment: It works fine but if i have more then 2 searches, it gives me an error msg:

Comment: The message is clear. You are trying to call _connection.Open()_ somewhere, but you haven't called _connection.Close()_ before. If these commands are all executed one after the other then open at the beginning and close at the end with one single try/catch that closes in case of error.